# Dynamic style, Data binding expressions not supported with attributes processed at compile time

Tags: apache-flex

I have a web site with flex, now I need to apply diferent styles for the same site.

I have a ConfigApp class, with the function getResorcesPath()

I tried to use:

```
<mx:Style source="{ConfigApp.getResourcesPath()}/styles.css"/>
```

But the error shows up "Data binding expressions not supported with attributes processed at compile time.".

How can I make the mx:Style "dinamic"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make the mx:Style "dinamic"?

You can't.  It is a compile time value; and needs to compile those styles into the app.

However, there is a way. You should review the [documentation on loading style sheets at run time](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=styles_10.html) .  Based on the instructions, you should:

First compile your style sheet into a SWF.

Second, load the SWF using the StyleManager.loadStyleDeclarations method.

Comment: yep. styles will be compiled into your application. to choose a stylesheet at runtime, you have to go with loading them using `StyleManager`

Comment: mx:Application title can be load dinamic? because <mx:Application (...) pageTitle="ConfigApp.getTitle()}" (xxx) > don't work...